# If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, 1-1, and on-to, then f maps Borel Sets to Borel Sets

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, on-to, and 1-1. Prove that if $A$ is a Borel set, then $f(A)$ is a Borel set.

Comment: Can you prove that such an $f$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot prove that if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then it maps Borel sets to Borel sets.

Comment: Aha. Can you prove that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for every Borel set $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's not worry about whether $f$ is a homeomorphism, it ends up not playing a role.

First, $f(C)$ is Borel when $C$ is closed. This is clear if $C$ is compact, because continuous maps send compact sets to compact (and therefore closed) sets. If $C$ is unbounded, we cannot quite say that $f(C)$ is closed by the same argument, but note that $C=\bigcup_n(C\cap[-n,n])$, so $f(C)=\bigcup_n f(C\cap[-n,n])$ is a countable union of closed sets.

It follows that $f(O)$ is Borel is $O$ is open, because $f(O)=f(\mathbb R)\setminus f(\mathbb R\setminus O)$ is a difference of Borel sets (since both $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\setminus O$ are closed). Note that we do not even need to use the assumption that $f$ is onto, but we are definitely using that $f$ is injective.

Let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of Borel sets $A$ such that $f(A)$ is also Borel. We have shown that $\mathcal F$ contains the open sets.

Note now that $\mathcal F$ is closed under complements. This is because if $f(A)$ is Borel, then so is $f(\mathbb R\setminus A)=f(\mathbb R)\setminus f(A)$ (again, the equality holds because $f$ is injective).

Finally, $\mathcal F$ is closed under countable unions, because if $f(A_n)$ is Borel for each $n$, then so is $f(\bigcup_n A_n)=\bigcup_n f(A_n)$.

This means that $\mathcal F$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of all Borel sets of reals, that is, $f(A)$ is Borel for each Borel set $A$.

---

Hmm... It turns out the question is a duplicate so it may end up being closed. Let me add some remarks just in case: If you want to argue that $f$ is a homeomorphism, which would certainly simplify things, note that since $f$ is injective, it must be monotone, and therefore (by continuity) it maps open intervals to open intervals. It follows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

This simplifies the argument, because we get not just that $f(A)$ is Borel if $A$ is Borel, but in fact we see that $f(A)$ has the same *Borel complexity* as $A$: If $A$ is open, so is $f(A)$, if $B$ is $F_\sigma$, so is $f(B)$, etc.

Trevor hints in a comment that the above is anyway not the most direct approach. As you can see in the answers to the other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6268/462) (the one this duplicates), descriptive set theory provides a very elegant alternative approach, via a theorem of Suslin, that if both a set $A$ and its complement are continuous images of a Borel set, then in fact $A$ is Borel.

Comment: Suslin's theorem can be found, for example, in Kechris's book on **Classical descriptive set theory**, or in Kuratowski's **Topology**.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $C$ be the collection of subsets $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f[A]$ is Borel.  Show that $C$ contains all the open sets and is closed under complementation and countable unions.

Comment: This hint only applies if you have already shown that the pointwise image of an open set is open, which (as we can see from Andres's answer) is not the most direct way to do the problem.